# Meeting the four deadlock conditions

Tags: c++, deadlock

I am having trouble understanding how to write a program that meets all four conditions necessary to create a deadlock. I have the following code that I think meets the condition for circular wait.

```
int main() {
thread thread1(Func1);
thread thread2(Func2);

thread1.join();
thread2.join();

cout << "Both threads have finished executing\n";
return 0;
}

void Func1() {
resource2.lock(); 
//do something
resource1.lock();
resource2.unlock();
resource1.unlock();
}

void Func2() {
resource1.lock();
//do something
resource2.lock();
resource1.unlock();
resource2.unlock();
}
```

So far it deadlocks every time I run it, but I know that all four conditions must be met to guarantee a deadlock. Can someone help me get a better understanding of the mutual exclusion, no preemption, and hold & wait conditions? Does this program already meet no preemption? I've been reading about it online, but every .edu seems to use the same textbook/slides. I would prefer any code to be written in C/C++;

Comment: I don't see where you disable interrupts.

Comment: @stark why does that matter?